# XAML: How to make element stay on top in this situation

Tags: xaml

I think this is best explained with an example

```
     <Grid>
        <StackPanel Panel.ZIndex="1">
            <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="red" Panel.ZIndex="100"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Panel.ZIndex="2">
            <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="blue" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
        </StackPanel>
     </Grid>
```

The result is that the blue rectangle wins, however I want to have the red one on top. This is easily fixed in this example of course. The real situation is that I'm dealing with multiple movable controls (that have z order between themselves) and I want some important bits of a control to be accessible even if something is ontop of that control.

Comment: By accessible do you mean visible? You might want to try using Opacity  then..

Comment: Unfortunately what you're describing is expected behavior, if you want to pass something like HitTestVisibility to something rendered underneath another object in the tree then you'll have to do that manually by literally passing those events to the object they're intended for when they're caught by the object actually receiving them.

Comment: I was hoping for something like a global zIndex but for now I solved it by popping the required bits out of their usual control and onto the main canvas where i can bring them to the front.